# Extending RxJS Subject to Contain Opertor

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

## The Problem

I've been trying to create a Subject that implicitly contains some transformation.

Consider this pattern:

```
const inputSubject = new Subject<number>();
const resultObservable = inputSubject.pipe(
  delay(1000),
  map(x => `${x * 5}`)
);
/** ... **/
resultObservable.subscribe(console.log);
inputSubject.next(5); // delay 1s, then prints "25"
```

Here I subscribe to one object and emit on another. Even though the two lines of code are next to one another, (without looking at how `resultObservable` is created) it's not immediately clear that `inputSubject.next(5);` creates this output. It is especially bothersome if I want to return both objects to the caller.

```
function getThing(){
  return {
    input: new Subject<number>(),
    output: inputSubject.pipe(
      delay(1000),
      map(x => `${x * 5}`)
    )
  };
}
```

It would be much nicer to have one of the following

```
function getThing(){
  return new TransformSubject<number,string>().pipe(
    delay(1000),
    map(x => `${x * 5}`)
  );
}
```

or

```
function getThing(){
  return new TransformSubject<number,string>(
    pipe(
      delay(1000),
      map(x => `${x * 5}`)
    )
  );
}
```

So that if you subscribe to the TransformSubject, you get results that have been transformed. If you emit into its `.next(v)`, you generate the next starting value.

---

### Part Way to a Solution

This is an attempt at the second approach. When somebody subscribes to the subject, they're actually returned the transformed results.

```
class TransformSubject<T,R> extends Subject<T>{
  private _tranf: OperatorFunction<T,R>;

  constructor(fn: OperatorFunction<T,R>){
    super();
    this._tranf = fn;
  }

  public subscribeT(observer){
    return super.pipe(
      this._tranf,
      share()
    ).subscribe(observer);
  }
}
```

Here it is in use:

```
const times5Subject = new TransformSubject<number, string>(
  pipe(
    delay(1000),
    map(x => `${x * 5}`)
  )
);

times5Subject.subscribeT(console.log);
times5Subject.next(10);
```

The issue is that I've implemented a new `subscribe` function called `subscribeT`. I can't override the original subscribe function because the transform part of the subject still relies on the old subscribe function. I'm not sure how to overcome that problem.

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing is possible by extending `Subject`. Do I need to implement `TransformSubject` from scratch or am I missing something?

Comment: I think subject should stay as a pure event emitter and not mixing any handling logic in it. You can create transform as a pipable reusable function instead.

Comment: That still means decoupling `input` and `output` at all times even when it often makes sense to abstract that away.

Comment: It is recommended not to subscribe directly to subject in the first place ( use .asObservable() to hide subject interface) , that actually implies subject's correct usage.

Comment: I get why you'd want to do that if you're returning it from (say) a library and you don't want the caller to be able to emit values (That's internal implementation details as far as the caller is concerned). If you want the caller to be able to emit values, returning `subject.asObservable()` doesn't work for obvious reasons. Your caller needs the subject in order to call .next() on it and emit a new value.

Comment: And if you really want to have custom class that allow emission and subscription , i'll suggest a more loose coupling approach other than inheritance. For instance return a custom object from constructor that expose desire interface and hide subject inside as an instance property